# Rails ajax executes many times

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

OK, so I've built a Rails app in which I have some controller which receive data from a form on homepage:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def some_method
    ...
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render "some_method_first" }
    end
  end
end
```

And inside some_method_first.js, I got:

```
$("#some_id").prepend("<section id='notice'>example!</section>");
$(function () {
  $("#notice").delay(500).fadeIn('slow', function () {
    $(this).delay(2500).fadeOut;
  });
});
```

The tricky part is when I try to input something on the homepage and submit, the first time it's fine, but second time, two "example!" appear, and third time, three "example!" section appear...

I am been driven crazy... Can anyone offer me some clue?

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are adding a new `section` each time.  If you don't refresh, the old ones will still be there, so you just keep prepending another one.

You need to check if `#notice` already exists, or better, just delete it each time:

```
$("#notice").remove();
$("#some_id").prepend("<section id='notice'>example!</section>");
```